# how to connect oracle database using C#

Tags: c#, oracle10g

I like to connect  oracle trough C# by the using following string

"CONNECT username/password@[//]host[:port][/service_name]"

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You really don't provide any information about how your code looks, what data provider you are using or anything.  Please in future formulate your question in a better way and include your code.

However, this might help you:  https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/

It lists all the different connection strings for different data providers for oracle in .net

Then you can use it as you need, such as this for the Oracle Data Provider for .NET (example from here: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/hol08/dotnet/getstarted-c/getstarted_c_otn.htm)

```
string oradb = "Data Source=ORCL;User Id=hr;Password=hr;";
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);  
conn.Open();
```

Comment: private static string name=System.Environment.MachineName;
        private static string CONNECTION_STRING =
      "User Id=livesig;Password=livesig;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=" +
      "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST="+name+")(PORT=1521))" +
      "(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)));";
      OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection();
      
      connection.ConnectionString = CONNECTION_STRING;
      connection.Open();